# How to debug Restlet?

Tags: java, restlet, restlet-2.0

When I POST to a Restlet, it says `415 Unsupported Media Type`, but there are no stack traces, nothing in the log, no errors returned, nothing. I tried setting a breakpoint on the first line of the method and restarting the server in debug mode, but it fails before it even gets to the first line. How can I tell what is wrong?

A get request to a different method works fine.

#### Version

Restlet 2.1

---

I found out the REST client I was using, [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher) had a bug and the encoding was not being set correctly no matter what, even though I set it to `application/json`. I had to close the tab and reload it and then it worked. It would still be nice to find a way to debug to find out exactly the reason for an error.

Answer (score 4):

You can enable traces in Restlet, as described below:

```
Engine.setLogLevel(Level.FINEST);
Engine.setRestletLogLevel(Level.FINEST);
```

Hope it helps.
Thierry